# YUI Compressor comments syntax error

Tags: yui-compressor

I use YUI Compressor in Symfony2 with assetic bundle.
I have a problem:

If a jquery file start with /* comments I get syntax error....
In order to get rid of it I need to delete all /* comments from all js files...
This is starting to be a problem as everytime I update other bundles the comments are returning.
Anyone have an idea how to sovle this? Is this a known issue?

YUI Compressor version: 2.4.8

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For me version 2.4.8 fixed the problem. Do the comments start with /*!  rather than only /* ?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot seem to find why this is happening. It is most likely a bug. If you use Dreamweaver, try using [this](http://www.trentmueller.com/blog/search-and-replace-wildcard-characters-in-dreamweaver.html) to ease your work. If you are not using dreamweaver, find your favourite program [here](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=using%20wildcards%20to%20search%20and%20replace).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding on your file.  I've had problems with YUI Compressor if my .js and .css files were not UTF-8.